# Encrypted Keystore instead of Location Path

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a enterprise level Kafka hosted in AWS Cluster. I'm trying to consume a topic from AWS Cluster. I need to use SSL protocol for connecting to servers.

From documentation i found that, i need to enable few properties,

```
ssl.keystore.password=test1234
ssl.key.password=test1234
ssl.truststore.location=/var/private/ssl/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=test1234
```

I have a problem here, i cannot store the keystore.jks and truststore.jks in the source. Our security does not allow storing sensitive data in the source.

Instead I have a encrypted keystore file, which I pull it from Vault.

Is there a possibility that i can use this encrypted keystore? I don't see such feasibility in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A local file path is needed for SSL certificates. You'll need a wrapper script before your code starts (or before the main method consumer logic) that will download the necessary information from Vault and fills in the properties files/configs

Or use a library that handles this, such as Spring Vault